# Datatable as datasource in ReportViewer

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, reportviewer

I want the table component in reportviewer control to be filled in with data from datatable. In other words, i want to use datatable as source for reportviewer control. I tried to create dataset, added datatable with exact columns that my datatable will have after programmatical fill in. Then I used the following code:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.TableName = "DataTable1";
 conn.Open();
 adapter.Fill(dt);
 ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode=ProcessingMode.Local;
 ReportDataSource source = new ReportDataSource("SampleDs", dt);
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
 ReportViewer1.DataBind();
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

However, that does not work. The only message I get is:

> An error has occurred during report processing. SampleDs.

Can anyone tell me how to solve issue or point out to the refference where full process of creating such report described,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overload you're using for the constructor of the [ReportDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251736.aspx) object is expecting the name of the data source in that first parameter.  You're not supplying this, you need the DataTable name.

Update your code to this and you should be OK:

```
ReportDataSource source = new ReportDataSource("DataTable1", dt);
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. Another question: if I want to add one more string value to report, is it possible to do without adding this value to datatable?

Comment: @seeker To be honest I'm not that familiar with ReportViewer so I'm not sure.  Try a few things and if you can't get it to work come back to SO and open another question showing your code and the issues you're encountering.  Of course it's pretty easy to add data to DataTables so maybe you should consider doing that.