# Data in my dataset is not showing in my ReportViewer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, reporting

I have a program that shows data in a datagridview. The data in the datagridview comes from a table in a dataset. The data looks good on the screen so I decided to add a way to print the data.

I created a new form, added a reportviewer control, and designed the report. I used my dataset as the datasource for the report.

My problem is, when i go to report tab which there my report resides, but it shows my report with only the headings, no data. It's like my dataset has no data in it!

So, my question is, what have I forgotten to do? The data is there, it shows up on one form (with the datagridview) but it doesn't show up on the reportviewer control (only the headings).

There was really no coding involved. I just made a new form, added the reportviewer control, designed the report and told it to use my dataset as the datasource. Typically, this works for me. I can't imagine why it's not working.

Thanks for any help or advice!

here is image of my problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6NrX.jpg

Comment: Even if there is little code involved, the fact that it isn't working means something is probably wrong with it. No one can really help without seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there one of two causes for this:
1. Either you need provide TableName in report datasource (take a look at [Datatable as datasource in ReportViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725634/datatable-as-datasource-in-reportviewer))

2. Or you need to call RefreshReport().

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkDIDTNbA6M

Again add data into your dataset from database before calling report

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\typroject\TYPROJECT\TYPROJECT\logindb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

    billDataSet b1 = new billDataSet();

    SqlDataAdapter s = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from TblOrder",con);

    s.Fill(b1,b1.Tables[0].TableName);

    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("orders",b1.Tables[0]);

    this.a.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);

    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

    this.TblOrderTableAdapter.Fill(this.billDataSet.TblOrder, d1.ToString(), 

    d2.ToString(), companyid);

    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```